# How to Bulk Insert in Cosmos DB with .NET Core 2.1 and Stream API

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to implement bulk insert with [this CosmosDB sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-dotnet-bulk-import-throughput-optimizer/blob/master/src/Program.cs). This sample is created with .NET Core 3.* and support of System.Text.Json.

When using the CreateItemAsync method, it works perfectly:

```
    var concurrentTasks = new List<Task<ItemResponse<Notification>>>();
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        entity.Id = GenerateId(entity);

        var requestOptions = new ItemRequestOptions();
        requestOptions.EnableContentResponseOnWrite = false; // We don't need to get the entire body returend.
        concurrentTasks.Add(Container.CreateItemAsync(entity, new PartitionKey(entity.UserId), requestOptions));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
```

However, I'm trying to see if I can reduce the number of RU's by streaming the data directly into CosmosDB, hoping CosmosDB doesn't charge me for deserializing JSON itself.

I'm working in .NET Core 2.1 and Newtonsoft.Json. This is my code that does not return a succesfull status code. The sub-status code in the response header is "0".

```
    Notification[] notifications = entities.ToArray();
    var itemsToInsert = new Dictionary<PartitionKey, Stream>();

    foreach (var notification in notifications)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
        JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);
        JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
                
        ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, notification);

        await jsonWriter.FlushAsync();
        await writer.FlushAsync();

        itemsToInsert.Add(new PartitionKey(notification.UserId), ms);
    }

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(notifications.Length);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<PartitionKey, Stream> item in itemsToInsert)
    {
        tasks.Add(Container.CreateItemStreamAsync(item.Value, item.Key)
            .ContinueWith((Task<ResponseMessage> task) =>
            {
                using (ResponseMessage response = task.Result)
                {
                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Received {response.StatusCode} ({response.ErrorMessage}).");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
            }));
    }

    // Wait until all are done
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

response.StatusCode: BadRequest
response.ErrorMessage: null

I'm assuming I don't serialize into the Stream in a correct way. Anyone got a clue?

**Update**

I discovered that the new System.Text.Json package also implements .NET Standard 2.0 so I installed it from NUget. Now I can copy the sample code from Github, mentioned earlier.

```
        Notification[] notifications = entities.ToArray();
        var itemsToInsert = new List<Tuple<PartitionKey, Stream>>();

        foreach (var notification in notifications)
        {
            notification.id = $"{notification.UserId}:{Guid.NewGuid()}";

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(stream, notification);

            itemsToInsert.Add(new Tuple<PartitionKey, Stream>(new PartitionKey(notification.RoleId), stream));
        }

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(notifications.Length);
        foreach (var item in itemsToInsert)
        {
            tasks.Add(Container.CreateItemStreamAsync(item.Item2, item.Item1)
                .ContinueWith((Task<ResponseMessage> task) =>
                {
                    using (ResponseMessage response = task.Result)
                    {
                        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Received {response.StatusCode} ({response.ErrorMessage}).");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }));
        }

        // Wait until all are done
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

I double checked that BulkInsert is enabled (or else the first method also won't work). Still there is a BadRequest and a NULL for errorMessage.

I also checked that the data isn't added to the container dispite the BadRequest.

Comment: Is key already in the database?

Comment: It might be worth setting position of memory stream to zero before you add it. 
`ms.Position = 0;`

Comment: @jdweng thank you, the key's are GUID's so they are always (globaly) unique.

Comment: If you run the code twice on an existing database you are putting the same values into the database twice.

Comment: @jdweng I know, so the ID is generated like this: $"{notification.UserId}:{Guid.NewGuid()}"; Every time a new GUID is generated. To be sure, I cleared the database of documents for this partition key.

Comment: Did you check to see if data got entered into the database.  May be the response status of zero is bad and the data was actually inserted into database.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the tip, I did. The data is not added. Do you know if there is some sort of server-side error logging?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-monitor-resource-logs

Comment: @jdweng thanks! I already got that in place, ticked all the boxes. But no error logging so far.

Comment: Since you are not getting logs maybe code isn't writing to database.

Comment: BadRequest errors might have an Error message that specifies which field might be the problem, the most common are: "id" (lowercase) field missing or not a string, the PartitionKey you are passing on the CreateItemStreamAsync method does not match the Partition key path property value (for example, you pass RoleId as PartitionKey parameter but your container has /SomethingElse as partition key path, or the document has no RoleId property with the same value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

I've setup my Cosmos Context with the following options:

```
var cosmosSerializationOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions();
cosmosSerializationOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase;

CosmosClientOptions cosmosClientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions();
cosmosClientOptions.SerializerOptions = cosmosSerializationOptions;
```

Hence the **`CamelCase`** convention. In my first (working) code sample, I would let the CosmosDB Context deserialize to JSON. He would serialize with this CamelCase convention, so my PartionKey `UserId` would be serialized into `userId`.

However, to reduce some RU's I will use the `CreateItemStreamAsync` that makes me responsible for the serialization. And there was the mistake, my property was defined like:

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

So he would be serialized to json `UserId: 1`.

However, the partition key is defined as `/userId`. So if I add the JsonPropertyName attribute, it works:

```
[JsonPropertyName("userId")]
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

...if only an error message would tell me that.

There is about 3% RU savings on using this `CreateItemStream` method. However, over time this would slowly save some RU's in total I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the stream is not readable. Hence the bad request.
I would make little modification to how `MemoryStream` is created:

```
foreach (var notification in notifications)
    {
        
        itemsToInsert.Add(new PartitionKey(notification.UserId), new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(notification))));
    }
```

Of course, I am using Newtonsoft.json for jsonConvert.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion but still receiving BadRequests. But with this answer I at least learned a more readable/compact way of serializing into a stream with Newtonsoft.

Comment: Let me run the example again.

Comment: See my answer/solution below. You suggestion also works if my Serialization attributes are correct